# No such object (32) error while trying to modify olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed LDAP and I am able to start it.
While I am trying to modify the olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif file I am getting "ldap_modify: No such object (32)" error.

Steps followed to modify

1) created a db.ldif file with below contains

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc= ec2,dc=internal

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc= ec2,dc=internal

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changeType: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}6zHtA20qkTmdLrJSfxo+VV3QLGS7m0CZ

2) ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif

SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)

I am using centos7 and LDAP version openldap-clients-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
openldap-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
openldap-servers-sql-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
openldap-servers-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
openldap-devel-2.4.44-21.el7_6.x86_64
collectd-openldap-5.8.1-1.el7.x86_64
compat-openldap-2.3.43-5.el7.x86_64

Please help me fix this!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for this result.

1. the entry actually doesn't exist,
2. it exists but you don't have permission to know that.

I suggest you try to search the `cn=config` database to see what it actually contains:

```
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b 'cn=config'
```

If the result is `No such object (32)`, then `gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth` doesn't have access to the config database on your system.

If the search does return output, check whether the entry `olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config` is actually listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to fix it I restarted slapd.service:

```
systemctl stop slapd.service
systemctl start slapd.service
```